Externalising Tikz with Nested Includes and Inputs
I've got a project laid out roughly as so:
/
| - Book.tex
| - bookheaders.sty
| - Chapters/
            | - Chapter1.tex
            etc.
| - Figures/
           | - Figure1.tikz
           etc.


Book.tex is the 'main' document.
The preamble (macros, packages, etc.) are all in bookheaders.sty, and called in Book.tex by \usepackage{bookheaders}.
The chapters are added using \include{Chapters/...} in Book.tex, as

...
\begin{document}
...
\include{Chapters/...}
...
\end{document}


The figures are added in each chapter using \input{Figures/...}.

Now I want to externalise these figures and put them in their own directory, since I've got a lot of them, but I think this file organisation is now causing issues. I've tried messing around with the commands listed in the Tikz externalise documentation, but I can't get it working. Any suggestions, or do I need to restructure this? I imagine the issue might be related to nesting include/input.
This is similar to Managing a project: separate .tex-files, externalized TikZ, folders but this solution didn't work for me.
EDIT 1
To be more specific, the error I'm getting is
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "GenFigs/Book-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalr
ealjob{Book}\input{Book}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'GenFigs/Book
-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have 
enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes
 it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simpl
y failed? Error messages can be found in 'GenFigs/Book-figure0.log'. If you con
tinue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

For context, GenFigs/ is the folder I'd like to have the externalised images go to, and so in Book.tex, after loading bookheaders.sty, I've got
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=GenFigs/]

The fix mentioned in Managing a project: separate .tex-files, externalized TikZ, folders doesn't work for me with the same error, albeit a different path.
EDIT 2
That issue has now somehow resolved itself? It's working when I compile locally but I'm not sure what's changed. If I figure out what I'll post an answer. Now I need to get it working on Overleaf...

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you explain, why it did not work for you?

@Mensch Thank you! Yes, apologies, I'll add that to the main post in an edit.

that message directs you to a second log file, which should provide some clue as to why it failed. what does that log say? note two things. (1) a flat directory structure is far, far, far easier. if you don't want to use one, at least be prepared to use one when troubleshooting. (there are ways around the problems, but they all involve at least some configuration and complications.) (2) the external library is unmaintained and the pgf/tikz position is that there are better options by now.

@cfr ah interesting, I didn't realise that it was unmaintained. What's the recommended method?

@Sam I don't think that's official. it's just what developers/maintainers have said on github in response to problems. the two methods I'm aware of and which they mentioned are memoize and robust-externalize. I've only personally tried the former. note that the docs for robust-externalize provide a comparison of the packages which is, imho, heavily biased towards the author's own solution. don't take the word of the robust-externalize docs with anything but a grain of salt where memoize is concerned. (memoize says much less about robust-externalize, but is much fairer.)

if you browse the memoize tag, you'll see I have a couple of introductory posts and some questions about issues which have basically all been resolved by updates. one disadvantage in comparison with external (and robust-externalize? not sure) is that the recommended method requires you to install additional software. on texlive, you can get away with just an extra perl module or so. on miktex, if you're on windows, you probably also need perl. how big a deal this is depends on you system etc.

@Sam also overleaf does not yet have either, as far as I know.
